# session expired error in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on asp.net MVC 3 application. I am facing an issue related to session expiration. When I am logged in and website is inactive for 10-15 minutes, I try to click any link, It says object reference null error. I want that when session is expired, on clicking any link, either I should be redirected to login page with error message that session expired, or popup with same message. how to implement it in asp.net MVC 3.

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: How are you handling authentication, FormsAuthentication or something custom?

Comment: A stack trace and example code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that your code grabs something from session state and then uses it without checking if it is null first.

I would suggest looking at that code, and adding the null check. if null, then redirect to the login page as you need.

Comment: >> It says object reference null error. What is it? Debug the code, I suspect n8wrl is correct. Also look at BNL's response and set you session/authentication time out correctly. I would lower them to 1,2 minutes and see if you can reproduce the problem more quickly, then understand the problem, then fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two timeouts normally seen in a .net web app.

The first is the session timeout. It is set in the sessionState tag.

```
<sessionState timeout="number of minutes" ...></sessionState>
```

The second is the forms cookie timeout. It is set in the authentication tag.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="number of minutes"/>
</authentication>
```

It looks like your session is timing out before your forms cookie times out.

It is better to have your session last a few minutes longer than the forms authentication cookie, that way the user can log back in within a few minutes and still have their session. I've had problems, such as the one you described, with setting them to the same value.